# Reprojecting polar to cartesian grid

Tags: python, image

I have a polar (r,theta) grid (which means that each cell is an annulus section) containing values of some physical quantity (e.g. temperature), and I would like to re-grid (or re-project, or resample) these values onto a cartesian grid. Are there any Python packages that can do this?

I am not interested in converting the coordinates of the centers of the cells from polar to cartesian - this is very easy. Instead, I'm looking for a package that can actually re-grid the data properly.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: That's not an easy problem, and it would be both interesting and a huge bear to write.  I think it would take me 2-3 days to come up with something horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for your answers - after thinking a bit more about this I came up with the following code:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.ndimage import map_coordinates


def polar2cartesian(r, t, grid, x, y, order=3):

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    new_r = np.sqrt(X*X+Y*Y)
    new_t = np.arctan2(X, Y)

    ir = interp1d(r, np.arange(len(r)), bounds_error=False)
    it = interp1d(t, np.arange(len(t)))

    new_ir = ir(new_r.ravel())
    new_it = it(new_t.ravel())

    new_ir[new_r.ravel() > r.max()] = len(r)-1
    new_ir[new_r.ravel() < r.min()] = 0

    return map_coordinates(grid, np.array([new_ir, new_it]),
                            order=order).reshape(new_r.shape)

# Define original polar grid

nr = 10
nt = 10

r = np.linspace(1, 100, nr)
t = np.linspace(0., np.pi, nt)
z = np.random.random((nr, nt))

# Define new cartesian grid

nx = 100
ny = 200

x = np.linspace(0., 100., nx)
y = np.linspace(-100., 100., ny)

# Interpolate polar grid to cartesian grid (nearest neighbor)

fig = mpl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(polar2cartesian(r, t, z, x, y, order=0), interpolation='nearest')
fig.savefig('test1.png')

# Interpolate polar grid to cartesian grid (cubic spline)

fig = mpl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(polar2cartesian(r, t, z, x, y, order=3), interpolation='nearest')
fig.savefig('test2.png')
```

Which is not strictly re-gridding, but works fine for what I need. Just posting the code in case it is useful to anyone else. Feel free to suggest improvements!

Comment: Just a tiny correction. I guess, it should be arctan2(Y, X) in your code.

Answer (score 7):

I came to this post some time ago when trying to do something similar, this is, reprojecting polar data into a cartesian grid and vice-versa. The solution proposed here works fine. However, it takes some time to perform the coordinate transform. I just wanted to share another approach which can reduce the processing time up to 50 times or more.

The algorithm uses the `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates` function.

Let's see a little example:

```
import numpy as np

# Auxiliary function to map polar data to a cartesian plane
def polar_to_cart(polar_data, theta_step, range_step, x, y, order=3):

    from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import map_coordinates as mp

    # "x" and "y" are numpy arrays with the desired cartesian coordinates
    # we make a meshgrid with them
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    # Now that we have the X and Y coordinates of each point in the output plane
    # we can calculate their corresponding theta and range
    Tc = np.degrees(np.arctan2(Y, X)).ravel()
    Rc = (np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)).ravel()

    # Negative angles are corrected
    Tc[Tc < 0] = 360 + Tc[Tc < 0]

    # Using the known theta and range steps, the coordinates are mapped to
    # those of the data grid
    Tc = Tc / theta_step
    Rc = Rc / range_step

    # An array of polar coordinates is created stacking the previous arrays
    coords = np.vstack((Ac, Sc))

    # To avoid holes in the 360º - 0º boundary, the last column of the data
    # copied in the begining
    polar_data = np.vstack((polar_data, polar_data[-1,:]))

    # The data is mapped to the new coordinates
    # Values outside range are substituted with nans
    cart_data = mp(polar_data, coords, order=order, mode='constant', cval=np.nan)

    # The data is reshaped and returned
    return(cart_data.reshape(len(y), len(x)).T)

polar_data = ... # Here a 2D array of data is assumed, with shape thetas x ranges

# We create the x and y axes of the output cartesian data
x = y = np.arange(-100000, 100000, 1000)

# We call the mapping function assuming 1 degree of theta step and 500 meters of
# range step. The default order of 3 is used.
cart_data = polar_to_cart(polar_data, 1, 500, x, y)
```

I hope this helps someone in the same situation as me.

Comment: great! ...minor correction is coords should be constructed from Tc and Rc, not Ac and Sc

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV 3.4 can do this now pretty easily with [warpPolar()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga49481ab24fdaa0ffa4d3e63d14c0d5e4)

Very simple to call:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Read in our image from disk
image = cv2.imread('washington_quarter.png',0)
plt.imshow(image),plt.show()
```

[image: Cartesian image]

```
margin = 0.9 # Cut off the outer 10% of the image
# Do the polar rotation along 1024 angular steps with a radius of 256 pixels.
polar_img = cv2.warpPolar(image, (256, 1024), (image.shape[0]/2,image.shape[1]/2), image.shape[1]*margin*0.5, cv2.WARP_POLAR_LINEAR)
# Rotate it sideways to be more visually pleasing
polar_img = cv2.rotate(polar_img, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)
plt.imshow(polar_img),plt.show()
```

[image: Polar image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do this more compactly with `scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform`. Here is some sample code:

```
import numpy as N
import scipy as S
import scipy.ndimage

temperature = <whatever> 
# This is the data in your polar grid.
# The 0th and 1st axes correspond to r and θ, respectively.
# For the sake of simplicity, θ goes from 0 to 2π, 
# and r's units are just its indices.

def polar2cartesian(outcoords, inputshape, origin):
    """Coordinate transform for converting a polar array to Cartesian coordinates. 
    inputshape is a tuple containing the shape of the polar array. origin is a
    tuple containing the x and y indices of where the origin should be in the
    output array."""

    xindex, yindex = outcoords
    x0, y0 = origin
    x = xindex - x0
    y = yindex - y0

    r = N.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    theta = N.arctan2(y, x)
    theta_index = N.round((theta + N.pi) * inputshape[1] / (2 * N.pi))

    return (r,theta_index)

temperature_cartesian = S.ndimage.geometric_transform(temperature, polar2cartesian, 
    order=0,
    output_shape = (temperature.shape[0] * 2, temperature.shape[0] * 2),
    extra_keywords = {'inputshape':temperature.shape,
        'center':(temperature.shape[0], temperature.shape[0])})
```

You can change `order=0` as desired for better interpolation. The output array `temperature_cartesian` is 2r by 2r here, but you can specify any size and origin you like.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any Python packages that can do this?

Yes! There is now – at least one – Python package that has a function to re-map a matrix from cartesian to polar coordinates: [`abel.tools.polar.reproject_image_into_polar()`](http://pyabel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/abel.html#module-abel.tools.polar), which is part of the [PyAbel package](https://github.com/PyAbel/PyAbel/).

(Iñigo Hernáez Corres is correct, `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates` is the fastest way that we have found so far to reproject from cartesian to polar coordinates.)

PyAbel can be installed from [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAbel) by entering the following on the command line:

```
pip install pyabel
```

Then, in python, you can use the following code to re-project an image into polar coordinates:

```
import abel
abel.tools.polar.reproject_image_into_polar(MyImage)
```

[Depending on the application, you might consider passing the `jacobian=True` argument, which re-scales the intensities of the matrix to take into the account the stretching of the grid (changing "bin sizes") that takes place when you transform from Cartesian to polar coodinates.]

Here is a complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import abel

CartImage = abel.tools.analytical.sample_image(501)[201:-200, 201:-200]

PolarImage, r_grid, theta_grid = abel.tools.polar.reproject_image_into_polar(CartImage)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(7,3.5))
axs[0].imshow(CartImage , aspect='auto', origin='lower')
axs[1].imshow(PolarImage, aspect='auto', origin='lower', 
              extent=(np.min(theta_grid), np.max(theta_grid), np.min(r_grid), np.max(r_grid)))

axs[0].set_title('Cartesian')
axs[0].set_xlabel('x')
axs[0].set_ylabel('y')

axs[1].set_title('Polar')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Theta')
axs[1].set_ylabel('r')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note: there is another good discussion (about re-mapping color images to polar coordinates) on SO: [image information along a polar coordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798333/image-information-along-a-polar-coordinate-system)

Comment: This is a nice example. However it gives me `TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer ` on python3.4. If you're the maintainer of the code you should check that out.

Comment: It seems your code transforms images on an index-grid, where the origin is always on a pixel. Sometimes, the origin will need to be in between adjacent pixels. The circle in your example becomes a non-straight line after transformation, partially because the circle on the left isn't centered in the image, partially b/c the origin is shifted half a pixel. You may experiment with the same data which puts the circle in the center `abel.tools.analytical.SampleImage(501).image[200:-200, 200:-200]` and then interpolated it to an 100x100 grid (was 101x101) and then do your transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take which, to me, is the most straightforward:

```
from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# List of thetas and rs for which your data is defined
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
r = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)

# Create a grid from those values
T, R = np.meshgrid(t, r)

# Convert to cartesian
xs = (R*np.cos(T)).flatten()
ys = (R*np.sin(T)).flatten()

# Define some arbitrary data at the (converted) x, y values 
zs = np.abs(xs + ys)

# Define a new cartesian grid 
X = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
Y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y) 

# Create the interpolating function
interp = LinearNDInterpolator(list(zip(xs, ys)), zs)
Z = interp(X, Y)
# Get rid of nasty values
Z[np.isnan(Z)] = 0


# Plot the data
fig = go.Figure([
    go.Scatter(x=xs, y=ys, mode='markers', marker=dict(size=zs)),
    go.Scatter(x=X.flatten(), y=Y.flatten(), mode='markers', marker=dict(size=Z.flatten()))
    
    ]
    )
fig.update_layout(showlegend=True, height=1000, width=1000)
fig.show()
```

The size of the markers reflects the quantity of interest

[image]