# Imshow in polar coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, imshow, polar-coordinates

I have disk simulation data with snapshots in a .dat file. I want to plot only one but in polar coordinates.

I have:

```
rho = np.fromfile(filename).reshape(128,384)
plt.imshow(np.log10(rho),origin='lower',cmap="Oranges",aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want something like that:

[image]

Ignore colors and cmap. They are not same simulation. Only the disk form is sought.

Comment: what's `rho`? pixel values?

Comment: you want to map a rectangle onto a disk?

Comment: we need to have at least one input/output matching example

Answer (score 6):

### Preliminary

To help establish this answer, I'm going to first make a generator for the data.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def make_r_theta_vals():
    thetas_radians = np.arange(0,2.01*np.pi,np.pi/100.)
    radii = np.arange(0,101,1)
    #meshgrid these to make a fuller array
    tr,rr = np.meshgrid(thetas_radians,radii)
    #generate fake z values
    z_vals = (75. * rr**(1./2.2)\
        + 50.*np.random.normal()*np.sin(tr) \
        + 20. * np.cos(tr) * np.sqrt(rr) \
        + np.cos(rr * np.pi / 100.) * np.sin(rr * np.pi/50.) * 6.)\
        * (np.sin(rr * np.pi/ 100.)**3. + 0.85)
    return thetas_radians, radii, z_vals
```

Here, `z_vals` is an `NxM` array, where `N` and `M` are the lengths of the r and theta values. In your question, this would correspond to `rho`, but I'd like to generalize this answer.

We can see that this produces a plot similar to your original plot,

```
def make_cartesian_plot():
    plt.clf()
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5,2])
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.15,0.18,0.8,0.8])
    thetas_radians, radii, z = make_r_theta_vals()
    ax.imshow(z,origin='lower',extent=[np.degrees(thetas_radians[0]),
                                        np.degrees(thetas_radians[-1]),
                                                   radii[0],radii[-1]])
    plt.savefig('cartesian.png')
```

with an output of

[image: a plot showing a changing radial pattern, plotted in cartesian coordinates]

### The Simple Way

To make this work in polar coordinates, we're going to use [pcolormesh](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html), along with the known r and theta values. If you don't have those, you will need to generate them similar to how I generated them in the first code snippet. Then, it's fairly easy:

```
def make_polar_plot():
    plt.clf()
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5,5])
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8],polar=True)
    thetas_radians, radii, z = make_r_theta_vals()
    ax.pcolormesh(thetas_radians,radii,z,edgecolors='face')
    #ec='face' to avoid annoying gridding in pdf
    plt.savefig('polar.png')
```

which produces:

[image: A polar plot showing a disk-like structure with a preference for a given angle]

Decorative choices (such as removing the tick labels) are omitted for simplicity.

### Polar on a Cartesian Grid

Conversely, the question as asked depicted a polar disk plotted onto rectangular grid. Assuming this is the desired output, we instead convert the `r`, `theta`, `z` to `x`,`y`,`z`. Here again, we used `meshgrid` to make a useful `x` and `y` and `pcolormesh` to handle the plotting.

```
def make_cartepolar_plot():
    plt.clf()
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5,5])
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.15,0.15,0.8,0.8])
    thetas_radians, radii, z = make_r_theta_vals()
    tr,rr = np.meshgrid(thetas_radians,radii)
    x_vals = rr * np.cos(tr)
    y_vals = rr * np.sin(tr)
    ax.pcolormesh(x_vals,y_vals,z,edgecolors='face')
    #ec='face' to avoid annoying gridding in pdf
    plt.savefig('carte_polar.png')
```

Here, the output is

[image: The polar plot shown above, now projected onto a Cartesian grid.]

Note that, for a more complicated data set, you may need to [see this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164570/reprojecting-polar-to-cartesian-grid).